# How to make sure a module is loaded in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is a problem I faced more than one. Here is an example file structure:

```
app.js
folder
-- index.js
-- module1.js
-- module2.js
```

From `app.js`, the entry point of my application, I require `folder/index.js`. This file itself is just a loader who requires all the other files in the directory. `module1.js` and `module2.js` both define some methods I want to use eventually. They are never directly required by `app.js` since `index.js` takes care of that and adds common helper utilities and applies some transformations to these modules.

All works well if I then use some methods defined in those files from `app.js` after I required them. But the problem comes when a method defined in `module2.js` wants to use a method defined in `method1.js` (or vice-versa). Sometimes it will work, sometimes not (in folders with multiple files I didn't get to find out when precisely it works and when it doesn't yet).

If, from `module2.js` I require `./index.js` and then use methods in it defined by `module1.js`, I sometimes get `Cannot read property 'myMethod' of undefined`. I assume it has to do with the order the modules are required by `index.js`, but I can't seem to find a solution to this common problem (other than duplicating code or not using methods of these other modules).

Is there a common solution to this problem? I tried doing something like this :

```
var modules = require(./index.js);

exports.myMethod = function() {
  if(!modules.module1 || !modules.module1.myOtherMethod) {
    modules = require('./index.js');
  }
  modules.module1.myOtherMethod();
};
```

But it doesn't to do anything, `modules.module1` is still undefined.

Comment: if you need module1, require module1, not index... if you need module2, require module2...

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit `index.js` alters the modules it requires by adding helper functions to them as well as providing parameters

Comment: Maybe it's time to rethink your architecture ;)

Answer (score 1):

It just sounds like `module` should `require` `module2`. That's the solution to `module1` needing to call methods in `module2`.

If you're worried about many calls to `require`, don't. That's standard practice in every programming language I've used (in particular look at the `import` statements in any Java program. Java is verbose, I know, but this is correct practice.)

It's definitely bad practice to look at code in one module and have no idea where anything comes from, because the require statements are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular dependency problem. Try moving some of the common functions to a third file and have `module1` and `module2` require it, or make sure that one of them requires the other in one way only.

Never ever require a file that requires the current file back.

Comment: While I agree from a "best practice" standpoint this is actually legal in Node.